# Isotope : reorder or shuffle elements based on width

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-isotope

I'm working on isotopes as you can see from the code I have achieved a basic filterable layout. Now I want to add some other functionality. After clicking a filterable item largest width element should come first on the fly.

Here in the code, as you can see when you click on red It is giving me the required layout ("One large Item and two small Items below it"). but in the case of blue, the smaller item is coming before the larger item.

[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/Wahed98666/pen/PVJQEw)

Feel free to clarify any doubts.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

```js
// init Isotope
var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.color-shape',
  layoutMode: 'fitRows'
});

// store filter for each group
var filters = {};

var filterFns = {
  // show if number is greater than 50
  numberGreaterThan50: function() {
    var number = $(this).find('.number').text();
    return parseInt(number, 10) > 50;
  },
  // show if name ends with -ium
  ium: function() {
    var name = $(this).find('.name').text();
    return name.match(/ium$/);
  }
};
$('.filters').on('click', '.button', function(event) {
  var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
  // use filterFn if matches value
  filterValue = filterFns[filterValue] || filterValue;
  $grid.isotope({
    filter: filterValue
  });
});


// change is-checked class on buttons
$('.button-group').each(function(i, buttonGroup) {
  var $buttonGroup = $(buttonGroup);
  $buttonGroup.on('click', 'button', function(event) {
    $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
    var $button = $(event.currentTarget);
    $button.addClass('is-checked');
  });
});
```

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.tile.wide.square {
  width: 100%;
}

.tile.small.square {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline;
}

.button-group {
  margin: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
}


/* color-shape */

.color-shape {
  height: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.color-shape.round {
  border-radius: 35px;
}

.color-shape.big.round {
  border-radius: 75px;
}

.color-shape.red {
  background: red;
}

.color-shape.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.color-shape.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}

.color-shape.wide,
.color-shape.big {
  width: 150px;
}

.color-shape.tall,
.color-shape.big {
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//npmcdn.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.js"></script>

<div class="filters">
  <div class="ui-group">
    <h3>Color</h3>
    <div class="button-group js-radio-button-group" data-filter-group="color">
      <button class="button is-checked" data-filter="">any</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".red">red</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".blue">blue</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".yellow">yellow</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="tile color-shape wide square red"></div>
  <div class="tile color-shape small square red"></div>
  <div class="tile color-shape small square blue"></div>
  <div class="tile color-shape wide square blue"></div>
  <div class="tile color-shape small square blue"></div>
  <div class="tile color-shape small square yellow"></div>
  <div class="tile color-shape wide square yellow"></div>
  <div class="tile color-shape small square yellow"></div>
  <div class="tile color-shape small square red"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`getSortData`](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/sorting.html#getsortdata) and [`sortBy`](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/sorting.html#sortby) to accomplish this.

to define the criteria/values to use when sorting use the `getSortData`

```
var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.color-shape',
  layoutMode: 'fitRows',
  getSortData: {
      wide: function(element){return element.classList.contains('wide') ? -1 : 1}
    }
});
```

and to instruct to sort with that use `sortBy`

```
$('.filters').on( 'click', '.button', function( event ) {
  var filterValue = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
  var sortValue = filterValue ? 'wide' : 'original-order';
     // use filterFn if matches value
    filterValue = filterFns[ filterValue ] || filterValue;
    $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue, sortBy: sortValue });
});
```

---

```js
// init Isotope
var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.color-shape',
  layoutMode: 'fitRows',
  getSortData: {
      wide: function(element){return element.classList.contains('wide') ? -1 : 1}
    }
});

// store filter for each group
var filters = {};

var filterFns = {
  // show if number is greater than 50
  numberGreaterThan50: function() {
    var number = $(this).find('.number').text();
    return parseInt(number, 10) > 50;
  },
  // show if name ends with -ium
  ium: function() {
    var name = $(this).find('.name').text();
    return name.match(/ium$/);
  }
};
$('.filters').on( 'click', '.button', function( event ) {
  var filterValue = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
  var sortValue = filterValue ? 'wide' : 'original-order';
     // use filterFn if matches value
    filterValue = filterFns[ filterValue ] || filterValue;
    $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue, sortBy: sortValue });
});


// change is-checked class on buttons
$('.button-group').each(function(i, buttonGroup) {
  var $buttonGroup = $(buttonGroup);
  $buttonGroup.on('click', 'button', function(event) {
    $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
    var $button = $(event.currentTarget);
    $button.addClass('is-checked');
  });
});
```

```css
.tile img { width: 100%; }
.tile {
  height: 400px;
  background: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover; 
}
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/* .tile.small { width: 50%; }
.tile.wide { width: 100%; } */
.tile.wide.square {
  width: 100%;
}
.tile.small.square {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline;
}

.button-group {
  margin: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
  
  /* color-shape */

.color-shape {
  height: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 4px solid black;
}
 
.color-shape.red { background: #fb6a6a; }
.color-shape.blue { background: #bebef9; }
.color-shape.yellow { background: #f3f36e; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//npmcdn.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

<div class="filters">
  <div class="ui-group">
    <h3>Color</h3>
    <div class="button-group js-radio-button-group" data-filter-group="color">
      <button class="button is-checked" data-filter="">any</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".red">red</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".blue">blue</button>
      <button class="button" data-filter=".yellow">yellow</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="tile color-shape wide square red"></div>
  <div class="tile color-shape small square red"></div>
  <div class="tile color-shape small square blue"></div>
  <div class="tile color-shape wide square blue"></div>
  <div class="tile color-shape small square blue"></div>
  <div class="tile color-shape small square yellow"></div>
  <div class="tile color-shape wide square yellow"></div>
  <div class="tile color-shape small square yellow"></div>
  <div class="tile color-shape small square red"></div>
</div>
```

---

updated demo at https://codepen.io/gpetrioli/pen/exGXBP

Comment: I appreciate you work but please hang on. I have one more doubt.

Comment: Can we achive this layout after sorting. ('https://i.ibb.co/G0pNVc8/Untitled2.png')

Comment: @MohammedWahedKhan you can but it it more involved. My approach would be to run a function before isotope and add a numeric/order attribute that i want (per color) and use that for the `getSortData` and `sortBy`.